# Conditionally block method override

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns

I have an application where the parent object has a method to perform validations and every child overrides the method to perform extra validations. Something like:

```
class Parent {
    virtual void DoValidations (Delegate addErrorMessage) {
        //do some validations
    }
}

class Child : Parent {
    override void DoValidations (Delegate addErrorMessage) {
         base.DoValidations(addErrorMessage); //the parent method is always called
         //do some extra validations
   }
}
```

I added a new "IsDisabled" property that when true the method will not perform any validations.

```
class Parent {
    boolean IsDisabled;

    virtual void DoValidations (Delegate addErrorMessage) {
        if (IsDisabled)
            return;
        //do some validations
    }
}
```

I also want that for every child, if the "IsDisabled" property is true, the extra verifications aren't performed. What is the better pattern to use here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would split that functionality off in a separate method:

```
private void DoValidations(Delegate addErrorMessage)
{
    if (!this.IsDisabled)
    {
        this.OnDoValidations(addErrorMessage);
    }
}

virtual void OnDoValidations(Delegate addErrorMessage) { }
```

Now, `OnDoValidations` can be overridden at will. The `IsDisabled` check will be done inside the base class.

Comment: Perhaps, `DoValidations` should be `public`.

Comment: I don't know. That is for OP to find out.

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is related to SOLID 'L' (Liskou substitution principle). I suggest you to use the following approach:

1) Create interface, for example:

```
public IValidator {
  void Validate(Delegate addErrorMessage);
}
```

2) Create abstract base class with abstract DoValidations() method:

```
public abstract class BaseValidator : IValidator {
  public void Validate(Delegate addErrorMessage) {
    DoValidations(addErrorMessage);
  }

  protected abstract DoValidations(Delegate addErrorMessage);
}
```

3) Inherit Parent from BaseValidator (or make your Parent as base class instead of BaseValidator):

```
public class Parent: ValidatorBase {
  public override void DoValidations(Delegate addErrorMessage) {
    // do validation
  }
}
```

4) Inherit Child from Parent:

```
public class Child : Parent {
  public override void DoValidations(Delegate addErrorMessage) {
    // do validation
  }
}
```

5) Now it's time to add IsDisabled property. We just need to modify ValidatorBase and IValidator:

```
public interface IValidator {
  bool IsDisabled {get; set; }
  void Validate(Delegate addErrorMessage);
}

public abstract class BaseValidator : IValidator {

  public bool IsDisabled { get; set; }

  public void Validate(Delegate addErrorMessage) {
    if(!IsDisabled) {
      DoValidations(addErrorMessage);
    }
  }

  protected abstract DoValidations(Delegate addErrorMessage);
}
```

6) Now use your IValidator validator = _factory.Create():

```
validator.IsDisabled = false;
validator.Validate();
```

Good luck!